# ssh works, scp hangs forever

Tags: 16.04, ssh, scp

I would like to copy files from my laptop to another machine - a headless TX2 -- over my home wifi network. Both my laptop and the TX2 are running Ubuntu 16.04 and both have the latest version of `openssh-server` (1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.4). I've set up public key authentication so that `ssh tx2` logs me onto the TX2 without a password. However, running `scp -v test.txt tx2:~/test.txt` stalls forever until I kill it with `Ctl-C`. The last line it prints before getting stuck is `debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t ~/test.txt`. I get the same problem when trying to `scp` in the other direction (from the TX2 to my laptop). `sftp -v tx2` gets stuck in the same way after printing `debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp`

Some other answers indicate that the problem can lie with the login scripts printing to the console. However, my `.bashrc` on the TX2 is the Ubuntu default and the problem persists even if I delete it.

Comment: As a further diagnostic check, you might try setting the remote user's login shell to dash instead of bash e.g. `chsh -s /bin/dash` or (if you're certain `/bin/sh` is not bash) `chsh -s /bin/sh`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you please try to secure-copy to a destination that contains no meta-characters (`~`), e. g. `scp -v test.txt tx2:/tmp/test.txt`. For regular users their home directory is usually the current directory during remote SCP operations.

Comment: Thanks, david. Trying to copy to `/tmp` (no special characters) has the same issue, it gets stuck after printing `debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /tmp/test.txt`. Changing the shell didn't seem to have an effect either.

Comment: Had a similar problem when connecting from ubuntu to wsl 1 running on the same machine with virtualization enabled. I solved it by disabling virtualization

Comment: For me it hangs after the line `debug1: Connecting to` and after a good minute if not more it completes the command fine.